Quiver representations isomorphic
i need some help understanding why 2 quiver representations are isomorphic.
Let $Q$ be the Quiver $1_\overrightarrow{a} ^\underrightarrow{b} 2$, let $N=S(2)$, $M=S(1)$ be two simple modules and let E= $k_\overrightarrow{1} ^\underrightarrow{0} k$ and $E‘= k_\overrightarrow{0} ^\underrightarrow{1} k$. Then $E$ and $E‘$ are not isomorphic.
Can someone please tell me why?

Let's recall what it means for two quiver representations $V \overset{b}{\underset{a}{\rightrightarrows}} W$ and $V' \overset{b'}{\underset{a'}{\rightrightarrows}} W'$ to be isomorphic.
We need isomorphisms $\varphi_1 : V \cong V'$ and $\varphi_2 : W \cong W'$ so that $b' \varphi_1 = \varphi_2 b$ and $a' \varphi_1 = \varphi_2 a$. That is, we need the following to squares to commute:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>\varphi_1>> V' @. @. V @>\varphi_1>> V' \\
@VVbV @VVb'V       @.    @VVaV @VVa'V \\
W @>\varphi_2>> W' @. @. W @>\varphi_2>> W'
\end{CD}
$$
For your examples $k \overset{0}{\underset{1}{\rightrightarrows}} k$ and $k \overset{1}{\underset{0}{\rightrightarrows}} k$, this means we want isomorphisms $\varphi_1 : k \cong k$ and $\varphi_2 : k \cong k$ so that the following squares commute
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
k @>\varphi_1>> k @. @. k @>\varphi_1>> k\\
@VV0V @VV1V          @. @VV1V @VV0V\\
k @>\varphi_2>> k @. @. k @>\varphi_2>> k
\end{CD}
$$
But an isomorphism $k \cong k$ is just multiplication by a nonzero element of $k$, so $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in k^\times$ and we want to know that
$$1 \varphi_1 = \varphi_2 0 \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \varphi_1 = \varphi_2 1$$
But these equations force $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 = 0$, which is not possible since we konw $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are invertible! Thus no such isomorphism exists.

I hope this helps ^_^

Thank you so much!! I understand it now :)
